# Selecting a string data type from a list

Tags: java

I want so that when I enter the item code *"kv2"* it will then list the details of the item. It will only work if I enter "1)".

I left it to do a selection based on the number because I couldn't figure out how to select the code by its name from the list.

This is the code:

```
System.out.println("\nPlease enter the item code from the list you wish to order");
int selection = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("\nYou have ordered: " + "\nItem Code: "
    + ((ItemListing) v.get(selection - 1)).getItemCode() + " " + "\nItem Description: "
    + ((ItemListing) v.get(selection - 1)).getItemDesc());
```

Output:

> 1)
>   Item code: #kv2
>
> Item Description: peas
>
> Item Weight in grams: 2.20
>
> Unit Price: $2.00
>
> Please enter the item code from the list you wish to order
>
> kv2

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kv2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at trekker.company.assignment.TrekkerCompanyAssignment.main(TrekkerCompanyAssignment.java:159)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What is the error? Show us stack trace

Comment: Please share your current code and your error log too.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to parse a non-number string to integer. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line.

```
int selection = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

You can't parse "kv2" as an int. That's why you got the exception.

Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kv2"